# Dropdown and bounce Segue anitimation

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to replicate the following segue animation as seen in **Secret** where it bounces on the bottom of the screen. I have searched the internet but can't find anything to help me.

[image]

I am looking for the segue animation to dropdown from the top and bounce on the bottom of the screen.

Currently I have this but it doesn't bounce.

```
- (void)perform {

    UIViewController *srcViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.4;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    [srcViewController.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [srcViewController presentViewController:destViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

If it helps I use the POP animation engine.

Comment: You should look into the UIView method, 
animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:

Comment: I think UIDynamics are more appropriate in order to reproduce the bouncing effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom transition using UIKit Dynamics to perform the animation.

Comment: So, first learn about how to customize the transition animation; then learn about UIKit Dynamics. There is in fact a WWDC video that shows you exactly what to do.

Comment: Thanks. I gave that video a watch